# How to get Instagram profile picture full-size?

Tags: image, api, instagram, photo, profile

How can I get HD profile picture using username or ID?
The photo quality of the data returned from the [https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1) link is quite bad
I found a link :
[https://scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=sKAqSMzXNpoAX8kSbuJ&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8TfmMkIN3kIgTX3Hhe0Z8GLDAOM4574wJCdMtqQxONWA&oe=62217575&_nc_sid=a9513d&dl=1](https://scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/%7Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%7D.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=sKAqSMzXNpoAX8kSbuJ&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT8TfmMkIN3kIgTX3Hhe0Z8GLDAOM4574wJCdMtqQxONWA&oe=62217575&_nc_sid=a9513d&dl=1)

You can download full-size profile photo from this link.